# Regex: repeat line pattern and share delimiter

Tags: regex

If have text like the following where i want to match a regex which will return the values behind the `:`. I don't care about the "Keys".

```
------
Alpha: Value1
Beta Beta Beta:
Gamma Gamma: Value 3
------
Alpha: Some value
Beta Beta Beta: Some other value
Gamma Gamma: And maybe another
------
```

For the part between the first and the second delimiter i know how i can build a regex with capture groups like

```
-{6}\s[a-zA-Z ]*: ?(.*)\s[a-zA-Z ]*: ?(.*)\s[a-zA-Z ]*: ?(.*)\s[a-zA-Z ]*: ?(.*)\s[a-zA-Z ]*: ?(.*)\s[a-zA-Z ]*: ?(.*)\s-{6}
```

Though as you can see i repeat the code for one line. Which leads me to my first question:
How can i repeat `[a-zA-Z ]*: ?(.*)\s` while keeping the capture group intact? `([a-zA-Z ]*: ?(.*)\s){3}` does not work ( i think i misunderstadt that grouping thing a bit).

And my second question is: how can i use the second delimiter as the beginning of the second part after it has been used as the end of the first part?

**Edit:**
Thanks to Poul Bak's comment i change my regex to `/(?<=:) ?(.*)/gm`.
But now i wonder how i can distinct the captures into their respective blocks?

Comment: If you use the 'multiline' and 'global' options you can do it a lot easier: (?<=:).*

Comment: @PoulBak Thank you!... Now i did as in the Edit No 1. But how can i distinguish to which block the captures belong if i don't want to count lines? E.g. what captures are between the first and the second, which captures between the second and the third and so on?

Comment: A simple to do it would be: /-+|(?<=: ?).*/gm   - Now you will match the lines with '-' too. Then iterate though the matches, when your match is some '-', you know a new block starts.

Comment: @PoulBak care to post this as an aswer, as you came up with this first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is over complicated.

If you use the '`multiline`' and '`global`' options you can do it a lot easier:

```
/(?<=:[ ]?).*/gm
```

If you want to check when a new block is started, you can use this regex:

```
/^[-]+|(?<=:[ ]?).*/gm
```

That will match lines with '--------' as well as the values. Now iterate through the matches, when you see the hyphens, you know a new block has started.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need: https://regex101.com/r/Ln1qsv/1

Simple regexp: `/(?<=: ).*$/gm`